# Java Error ArrayIndexOutofBounds

Tags: java

i got a code that i am implementing from another but i get the error of Java `ArrayIndexOutofBoundsException` can someone help me? I am not sure of what to do it might be the codes that trigger the error

the data in the file is

```
Username|HashedPassword|no.of chips
```

code is below

```
public static void DeletePlayer()throws IOException{
    File inputFile = new File("players.dat");
    File tempFile = new File ("temp.dat");

    BufferedReader read = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(inputFile));
    BufferedWriter write = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(tempFile));

    ArrayList<String> player = new ArrayList<String>();
    try {
        String line;
        Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Please Enter Username:");
        String UserN = reader.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Please Enter Chips to Add:");
        String UserCadd = reader.nextLine();

        while((line = read.readLine()) != null){
            String[] details = line.split("\\|");
            String Username = details[0];
            String Password = details[1];
            String Chips = details[2];
            Integer totalChips = (Integer.parseInt(UserCadd) + Integer.parseInt(Chips));
            if(Username.equals(UserN)){
                line = Username + "|" + Password + "|" + totalChips;
                write.write("\r\n"+line);
            }

        }
        read.close();
        write.close();
        inputFile.delete();
        tempFile.renameTo(inputFile);
        main(null);
    }catch (IOException e){
        System.out.println("fail");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
String[] details = line.split("\\|");
        String Username = details[0];
        String Password = details[1];    
        String Chips = details[2];
```

It seems that your details array has only one or two elements. The moment, you try to get something from the array, for an index that is out of (the existing) range, that Exception is thrown.

Are you sure your file doesn't end with an empty line ?

add the line:

```
System.out.println("length: " + details.length);
```

right after your split method, or print out all the element of the details array, that will tell you how many elements there are, and how many times you try to do this for which values.

Answer (score 0):

In this code:

```
    while((line = read.readLine()) != null){
        String[] details = line.split("\\|");
        String Username = details[0];
        String Password = details[1];
        String Chips = details[2];
        //...
    }
```

You must check if the user input is at the expected format, in your case,

> joe|g00d|12

The minimal check is to have 3 elements separated by `|`. e.g.

```
    while((line = read.readLine()) != null){
        String[] details = line.split("\\|");
        if (details.length != 3) {
            System.out.println("Bad input, try agains...");
            continue;
        }
        String Username = details[0];
        String Password = details[1];
        String Chips = details[2];
        //...
    }
```

Note that you should `String#trim()` your inputs in order to strip leading and ending whitespaces (this allows an input like `joe | g00d | 123`), and you still can have an error when parsing the number of chips which has to be an integer. I would also certainly check that.